# For SQL, how to use group by twice but only order by sum() within the 2nd group

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

The table records credit card transactions where each row is one record.

The columns are: transaction_id, customerID, dollar_spent, product_category.

How can I pick up the 3 customerID's from each product_category that have the highest dollar_spent within that category?

I was thinking about something like:

```
select product_category, customerID, sum(dollar_spent) 
from transaction
group by product_category, customerID
order by sum(dollar_spent) desc limit 3
```

but it failed to pass. Removing "limit 3" helped it to pass but the whole result is sorted solely by sum(dollar_spent), not by sum(dollar_spent) within each product_category.

Searched on StackOverflow but didn't find anything relevant. Could someone help me with this? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you are looking for is a windowed function.

I added the `row_number` function to your select ordered by the amount of money spent, this basically ranks customer spending by product.

Then since you can not use a windowed function in a where clause (unfortunately) i had to create an outer query to filter on the `row_number` results

```
select * from( 
   select product_category, customerID, sum(dollar_spent), 
   row_number() over (partition by product_category order by sum(dollar_spent) desc) as rowNum
   from transaction
   group by product_category, customerID
) as data
where rowNum <= 3
order by product_category, rowNum
```

here is a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/urA3kbd9JeYed7xGUEWref/6)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your help! Just one thing: in the window function, how does SQL know the sum(dollar_spent) is performed for each customerID, instead of a "big" sum over all records within that partition? (which will only give 1 number per partition)

Comment: I think I know the answer... is it because if it's a "big" sum, it can't be used to order by, since there's only 1 value in each partition?

Comment: it knows because in the group by we specified customerID, so all aggregate functions like `sum` are going to be partition by it